# Can we use "Had that" to mean "would that"?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, grammaticality, conditional-constructions

Recently, I came across a sentence starting with *Would that*. By searching over ELL stackexchange I found [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/15664/3448) that *would that* is an obsolete way of saying *if this was true*. Now what came to my mind is that we sometimes start a sentence with *had* to mean the same thing, e.g.

> Had I been a millionaire.

My question is can we use the following types of constructions:

> 1. Had that I were a millionaire.
> 2. Had it been that I were a millionaire

Does both of them convey the same meaning?

Answer (score 2):

No. Start by removing the inversion: "Had I been a millionaire" becomes "(If) I had been a millionaire". "Had that I were a millionaire" would become something like "(If) I had were a millionaire", which doesn't make any good sense. For a conditional phrase beginning with "had", you need to start with a good phrase in the past perfect, and then move the "had" out front. More examples:

"If I had gone to school" => "Had I gone to school,"

"If I had thought it was a good idea" => "Had I thought it was a good idea,"

But "had been" is probably the most common verb to use with this construct.

Comment: Is this sentence correct: _"Had it been that I were a millionaire"_?

Comment: @user31782 a little awkward in my opinion, but valid.

Comment: I've edited my question. Now could you explain in a little detail why it is awkward?

Comment: @user31782 because it uses more words than "had I been a millionaire" which says the same thing in a less complicated way.

Comment: I am not saying "_had I been a millionaire_", I am saying for "_If it had been that I were a millionaire_".