# "Would not that we should not" double negative?

Tags: word-meaning, modal-verbs, multiple-negation

From Literary English Reading:

> I would not that we should not trespass against the Divine Law for justice.

What is this construction? Is this "should" the same as "would"? Not like "It is important that you do it."?

Comment: Related: [Starting a sentence with “would that…”](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/15663/3281).

Comment: Eh? That second *not* is surely an error, unless the writer is expressing the very heterodox opinion that trespassing against Divine Law is desirable.

Comment: I don't know what "From Literary English Reading" means, but quite apart from the appallingly clumsiness of the double negation, such use of ***would*** is hopelessly poetic / archaic. Technically speaking your example is "grammatical", but I don't think it would be in the interests of most learners to familiarise themselves with such usages (or, God forbid, *repeat* them! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers If you are reading or required to read older texts, it's still useful to understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's a dated (often marked as "literary" in dictionaries) use of the verb "would" in the meaning of "desire", "wish".

> And yet I **would** it were to give again. (Romeo and Juliet)
>
> I **would** it might prove the end of his losses. (The Merchant of Venice)